# Tikz How to unset/cancel/disable text width?

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-styles

I want to style a bunch of nodes using a complex Tikz style `generalStyle`, defined as

```
\tikzstyle{generalStyle}=[draw,... lots of options here..., text width=50pt]
```

Now, the design of an illustration is never as perfectly regular as a code, and I want to make one exception: One node must be styled exactly like the others, except that its content must be displayed without line-breaks. In other words, I want to locally *cancel* the `text width`.

I have tried the *usual suspects*, including:

```
\node[generalStyle, text width=none] {A long text};
\node[generalStyle, text width=0]    {A long text};
\node[generalStyle, text width=-1]   {A long text};
```

but none of them work (1st=>Error, 2nd and 3rd are interpreted literally).

How can I cancel the `text width` styling option in TikZ?

*Update:* As pointed out by [user4035](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/4035/user4035) below, the following will work perfectly

```
\node[generalStyle, text width=]   {A long text};
```

Here is a complete example:

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix,positioning}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \tikzstyle{generalStyle}=[draw,rounded corners=3pt, text width=50pt,text centered]
    \matrix[matrix of nodes,nodes=generalStyle] (a) {
        x & \ldots &  |[fill=blue!20]| I'd like to see the complete label of this node over a single  line (no wrapping)
    \\};
    \matrix[matrix of nodes,nodes=generalStyle, below=of a.south west, anchor=north west] (b) {
        x & \ldots &  |[fill=blue!20, text width=150pt]| I could extend the node width\ldots
    \\};
    \matrix[matrix of nodes,nodes=generalStyle, below=of b.south west, anchor=north west] (c) {
        x & \ldots &  |[fill=blue!20, text width=150pt]| \ldots but then it would not work if the text changes. It would be much better to locally {\bfseries unset} the {\ttfamily text width} option: How to do that?
    \\};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

and the output of its compilation:

[image: Use case for a post-facto cancellation of text width in TikZ]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I used `text width=` as the property for the node, whose text width you want to disable, and it worked:

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix,positioning}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \tikzstyle{generalStyle}=[draw,rounded corners=3pt, text width=50pt,text centered]
    \matrix[matrix of nodes,nodes=generalStyle] (a) {
        x & \ldots &  |[fill=blue!20,text width=]| I'd like to see the complete label of this node over a single  line (no wrapping)
    \\};
    \matrix[matrix of nodes,nodes=generalStyle, below=of a.south west, anchor=north west] (b) {
        x & \ldots &  |[fill=blue!20, text width=150pt]| I could extend the node width\ldots
    \\};
    \matrix[matrix of nodes,nodes=generalStyle, below=of b.south west, anchor=north west] (c) {
        x & \ldots &  |[fill=blue!20, text width=150pt]| \ldots but then it would not work if the text changes. It would be much better to locally {\bfseries unset} the {\ttfamily text width} option: How to do that?
    \\};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Ouch! Just when I thought I had tried it all :)
Thanks a lot!